# Listview display empty rows when scanning Bluetooth devices around me

Tags: java, android

I made Bluetooth Scanner application which scans devices around me and displays it in listview. It display the Bluetooth devices for me with lots of empty rows in Listview. It can only scan devices with the name start with "*". Can anybody please guide me to remove these empty rows?

```
      private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("Action",action);

        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            statusTextView.setText("Finished");
            searchButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String name = device.getName();
            String address = device.getAddress();
            String rssi = Integer.toString(intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI,Short.MIN_VALUE));
            //Log.i("Device Found","Name: " + name + " Address: " + address + " RSSI: " + rssi);

            if (!addresses.contains(address)) {
                addresses.add(address);
                String deviceString = "";
                if(name == null || name.equals("") ) {
                   // listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    System.out.println("Name is null");
                    } else if(name.charAt(0) == "*".charAt(0)){
                     deviceString = name + " - RSSI " + rssi + "dBm";
                }
                bluetoothDevices.add(deviceString);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};
```